# Rank a Spark stream dataset column

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, user-defined-functions

Im using Spark 2.3.1's Structured Streaming API. Is it possible to rank values in a column of a spark stream dataframe? I tried using the following code to then realize after the exception message that its not possible for stream context to iterate over the entire window.

```
.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(Window.orderBy($"transactionTime")))
```

throws

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets

Can anyone help me with an idea to calculate rank/percentile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that window operations are not supported in spark structured streaming api yet.
Look forward to the upcoming releases from Apache Spark

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately there is no useful API to do what you need, although I tried workaround using Scala `groupBy` and `mapGroupWithState`, e.g.:

```
val stream = ...

stream
      .groupByKey(_.id)
      .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(<function>)
```

and `<function>` will receive Iterator over your data. You may sort it and implement `rank`, `dense_rank` etc.

However, you have requested window without partition key information(which will lead to OOM issues for huge data volume), in this case, you may add same value for all records using `withColumn`.

Note: you don't need to keep state in `GroupState`, you just need API to do what you need.

Hope it helps!